# Jest coverage not picking expected files

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage

I'm trying to integrate Jest unit test to my project and I current get stuck on coverage configuration.
Below are my folder structure of my project

```
--jest.config.js
--package.json
--src
----main
------webapp
--------|test   // folders to contains test case files
-----------|NoData.test.js  // just a sample test case for 
--------|components   // folder to contains componnents
-----------|NoData.js    // sample component for writing test
--------|pages,...    // folders to contains code files
```

I want to collect coverage for all of my code files under component folder, then here is my Jest config, after many tries and Google searches

```
{
  "roots": ["./src/main/webapp"],
  "testMatch": ["**/src/main/webapp/test/**/*.test.js"],
  "reporters": [ "default", "jest-junit" ],
  "testResultsProcessor": "jest-junit",
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./jest.setup.js"],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|gif|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/src/main/webapp/components/**/*.{js}"
  ]
  "forceCoverageMatch": ["**/src/main/webapp/components/**/*.js"],     // I have to include this because without this, coverage is "Unknown", dont know why
  "coverageReporters": ["html", "text", "text-summary", "json-summary", "cobertura"]
}
```

And the script for test on package.json

```
"test-cov": "jest --collectCoverage --watchAll"
```

However, the coverage report is not as my expectation.

- Expectation: all source files under /components listed on report
- Actual: only files that have testcase listed

```
File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 components        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  NoData.js        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                  
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: You probably don’t want `forceCoverageMatch` or `coveragePathIgnorePatterns`. The first is causing your test files to be included in coverage and the latter isn’t as effective as negated globs in `collectCoverageFrom`. You can also restructure your project so source and test code are sibling directories to make configuration simpler. What source files are you expecting to have been tested but weren’t?

Comment: Thanks @morganney for yoru feedback. But without "forceCoverageMatch", my coverage result become all `Unknown%`, I added it when try fixing `Unknown%` issue
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Removing `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` does not resolve the my issue.

Comment: Hi @morganney, I have removed `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` and update `forceCoverageMatch` following your feedback. I also updated question that focus on the issue "Not all code files listed up on coverage report". Plz help take a look and tell me if you have any other idea

Comment: Hi all! I finally sorted out my issue. Below solution works for me:
1. change `collectCoverageFrom`
From `**/src/main/webapp/components/**/*.{js}`
To: `**/src/main/webapp/components/**/*.js`

2. Remove `forceCoverageMatch`
With the change in #1, I dont need `forceCoverageMatch` anymore. I completedly have no idea why the change in #1 can resolve `Unknown%` issue that I suffered before.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, if you remove the braces `{}` from your `collegeCoverageFrom` glob things work as expected:

```js
collectCoverageFrom: [
  '**/src/main/webapp/components/**/*.js'
]
```

Moreover, you don't need `forceCoverageMatch`, as that will cause your test files to be included in coverage collection as well.

Removing the braces `{}` from your `collegeCoverageFrom` glob works because Jest uses [`micromatch`](https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch) for glob matching. In turn, `micromatch` uses [`braces`](https://github.com/micromatch/braces) to support brace expansion in globs. Under [Escaping](https://github.com/micromatch/braces?#escaping) --> **Single items** you can find the documentation:

> Following bash conventions, a brace pattern is also not expanded when it contains a single character:
>
> ```js
> console.log(braces.expand('a{b}c'));
> //=> ['a{b}c']
> ```